# How do I find out if VLC is using hardware rendering/decoding at this moment?

Tags: vlc-media-player, gpu

Let's say I am currently playing a video in VLC. How do I find out if VLC is using hardware (GPU) rendering, or decoding, at this moment?

This question is *not* about enabling using the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **Process Explorer** (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)

In Process Explorer find `vlc.exe` playing a video file, right click and choose `Properties...`. Click `GPU Graph`. Top graph should display GPU usage.

Try enabling and disabling GPU video decoding in VLC and see the graph.

More GPU usage - means VLC decoding video using GPU.

Because you need to restart VLC to apply changes - you should open properties of actual vlc.exe instance.

[image: VLC GPU Usage panel]